# Google Chrome Extension: Getting Started Error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to learn how to create my own extension so I went to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted in order to get started.

All I did was read through the page and download their example files. I know it doesn't work because after unpacking in the developer mode, when I click on the icon, an error is caught (from popup.js) and says "Cannot display image. No response from Google".

I don't have much experience with JavaScript, all I know is that an error occurs!

The extension is supposed to "show a Google image result for the current page". There have been previous questions about the Getting Started page for Google Chrome extension, but there was a different example in the past and I couldn't find any information on this specific example.

If anyone could help or explain why it doesn't work, I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: Did you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037689/chrome-extension-made-according-to-official-tutorial-not-working)?

Comment: any error detail in console (in background, content script?)

Comment: AJAX Web Search API got taken down. Didn't see that question before, thanks!